# Check if char is a vowel using switch-case

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to check if each character in a string using switch a statement inside a while loop. So far I have this:

```
//f and g - vowel and consonant count
        int f, g, ind;
        f = 0;
        g = 0;
        ind = 0;
        char letter = sentence.charAt(ind);
        
        while (letter != sentence.charAt(ind)) {
            switch (letter) {
                case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y':
                    f += 1;
                    ind += 1;
                    break;
                    
                //in case it's a number, the code will pass to the next char
                case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9:
                    ind += 1;
                    break;
                 
                //in case it's a special character, the code will pass to the next char
                case '`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '-', '_', '+', '=', '\\', '|', ';', ':', ',', '.', '/', '?':
                    ind += 1;
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    g += 1;
                    ind += 1;
                    break;
                    
            }
        }
```

For some reason it just returns 0 for both variables. Any suggestions? I'm to this btw so don't be *too* mean (a little bit is fine if I did something dumb). Also, if anyone has a more efficient way to check if the char is a special character, that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Why_, though? What did you write this code for?

Comment: It literally just counts the vowels and consonants in an inputted string. It's for school. It doesn't necessarily have a purpose.

Comment: Remember to be explicit if you're asking homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, because most homework questions have barely anything to do with the kind of code we write in real life, so the kind of answers you get for homework vs "real questions" are incredibly different. (for example, you'd never write this kind of code, you'd just use a regular expression matcher)

Comment: Ah, yes. Should have specified. It's really just a learning exercise.

Comment: you still can: please edit your post =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `letter` never changes, so you always test the same character. Your while loop will stop when it reaches the first character that is different from the first one, so it will stop soon.

By the way, you may lighten your code calling consonants directly:

```
int f = 0, g = 0; // vowel and consonant counters
int ind = 0; // character index

while (ind < sentence.length()) {
    char letter = sentence.charAt(ind);
    switch (letter) {
        case 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U', 'y', 'Y':
            f += 1;
            break;

        case 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 
             'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'p', 'P', 
             'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'v', 'V', 'w', 'W', 
             'x', 'X', 'z', 'Z':
            g += 1;
            break;
                
        default:
            break;
    }

    ind += 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see that I put ```ind``` instead a variable I made earlier in the prgoram ```a = sentence.length()```

Comment: I forgot Q ^^ Seems like I should learn my alphabet a little bit

Comment: :) No one cares about q.